# How to configure NDK project in Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have been trying to configure Android Studio for NDk by following [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) article and [this](http://www.jianshu.com/p/9f010cd67cdc) article. The following are the contents of my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Sat Aug 08 09:36:53 IST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

Following is the contents of build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and finally the build.gradle(module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0 rc3"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.opaxlabs.nativetest"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel =  15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel =  22
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
        android.buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
            }
        }
    }
    android.ndk{
        moduleName = "native"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

when I try to sync gradle files I get the following error:

```
Error:No such property: android for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig
```

the following paths are defined in local.properties

```
ndk.dir=/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=/opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk
```

so it looks like I have missed something only I can't locate it. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your build.gradle(module), the **android.buildTypes** block needs to outside of the **android** block. So it should look like this:

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0 rc3"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.opaxlabs.nativetest"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel =  15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel =  22
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }
    android.ndk{
        moduleName = "native"
    }
}
```

Comment: For those who migrate from 0.2.0 to 0.4.0 NOTE: += does not work in 0.4.0 anymore, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-0.2.x---0.4.0

Answer (score -2):

```
NDK Build option

ndk {
  moduleName "SeePlusPlus" // Name of C++ module (i.e. libSeePlusPlus)
  cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions" // Add provisions to allow C++11 functionality
  stl "gnustl_shared" // Which STL library to use: gnustl or stlport
}
```

Comment: sorry for downvote, but your gradle script is not respecting Gradle 2.5 syntax. Please see here why : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental