# No such property: useLibrary for class

Tags: android, gradle

My project is using ndk on Android Studio.
So, build.gradle is as followings:

```
...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
    }
...
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        useLibrary = 'org.apache.http.legacy'
...
    android.ndk {
...
```

At that time, I got an error message (Error:No such property: useLibrary for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig).

How can I solve it?

Comment: You can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889657/how-to-configure-ndk-project-in-android-studio-1-3

Comment: Thanks, Annop. However, my concern is about "useLibrary".

Comment: It was solved using "compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'".

Comment: This Doesn't work for me and I am facing similar issue :(

Comment: Use  "compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.cli‌​ent:4.1.2'" instead of useLibrary = 'org.apache.http.legacy'