# What has useLibrary changed to in gradle experimental 0.6.0-alpha1?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental, android-uselibrary

I am trying to port my gradle.build over to gradle experimental. I have modified my existing android configuration over as below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion = compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion = buildTools
    useLibrary "org.apache.http.legacy"
    defaultConfig.with {
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 13
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = compileSdk
        versionName = fullVersion
        multiDexEnabled = true
    } 
}
```

However, upon compiling, I seem to get the error:

> Error:(148, 1) A problem occurred configuring root project.> Exception
>   thrown while executing model rule:model.android @ build.gradle line
>   145, column 1> Could not find method useLibrary() for arguments
>   [org.apache.http.legacy] on root project

Probably since I am unsure what has `useLibrary` been modified to. If I comment this out, the build goes on for a significant till it fails to find the http methods it might be expecting from the above library. Can someone please provide some pointers on how do I got about including this library in gradle experimental?

Comment: Probably, going to try if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503431/no-such-property-uselibrary-for-class solves my problem.

Comment: any idea guys? I haven't been able to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work to use "org.apache.http.legacy" both regular gradle and gradle-experimental

Remove the useLibrary line:

```
useLibrary "org.apache.http.legacy"
```

Add to gradle(module):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope not too late. Put org.apache.http.legacy.jar file under libs folder...
And include this in your dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```